# folder which is on external memory(SD card) should be accessible only to specific android app.....Is there a way?

Tags: android, database, passwords, android-sdcard

Actually my android app takes images and stores into external storage rather than internal memory because of space constraints. the images must be available only to that particular application only

Though datas in sd card are accesscible by all application, I want my images to be stored in external but it must be secure that no other app should use those images.

Is there a way that i can programmatically protect that specific folder with password if so only that android application can use the folder contents??

Another question if i store my application database itself in external memory.  will the database can be accessible by another application?

Pls help me in this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ensure that is to install the application on the SDCard directly. All private data will be stored there then (invisible to anyone but you).

To do so, just put this parameter in the AndroidManifest file, at "manifest" tag:

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using -

```
SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(String, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)
```

You can simply pass "/sdcard/info.db" as the first and null as the second parameter.

And go through on google search you can get many applications which are used to protect file by user's password.

Comment: are you sure info.db cant be accessible other than my speific application if i store that in sdcard???